# Hi I wonder how I can put the language elements to the right so that there is space between languages and

Tags: html, css

Hi I wonder how I can  put the language elements to the right so that there is space between languages and ...
In the navigation bar so that the visitors know where the Languages are and the other elemnts are
Thank you for your help! ( :

```css
.code {
    overflow: auto;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
}
/* ~~ Top Navigation Bar ~~ */

#navigation-container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 70px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.8;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.navigation-bar {
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
}



#navigation-container img {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
}

#navigation-container ul {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
}

#navigation-container li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  display: inline;
}

#navigation-container li a {
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 70px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
@media (max-width: 1000px){
  #navigation-container li a{
    font-size: 3vw;
    padding: 5px 1vw
  }
}

#menu {
  float: center;
}

a:hover {
 background-color: #0099cc;
}
 hr {
 color: darkgray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Welcome </title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="text.css" type="text/css">
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 </head>
 <body>
   <div class="navigation-bar">


    <div id="navigation-container">

      <img src="Bildschirmfoto%202017-10-08%20um%2012.01.55.png">

      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Who are we ?</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Newest</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">The Best</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">English</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Deutsch</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Français</a></li>
     
      </ul>
        
    
        
     <hr >
    </div>
   </div>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap your menu elements in one div and the languages in another div. Then you use flexbox on the parent element. You can check my example below.

Here is a great link if you want to learn more about flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.code {
    overflow: auto;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
}
/* ~~ Top Navigation Bar ~~ */

#navigation-container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 70px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.8;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.navigation-bar {
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
}



#navigation-container img {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
}

#navigation-container ul {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
}

#navigation-container li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  display: inline;
}

#navigation-container li a {
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 70px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
@media (max-width: 1000px){
  #navigation-container li a{
    font-size: 3vw;
    padding: 5px 1vw
  }
}

#menu {
  float: center;
}

a:hover {
 background-color: #0099cc;
}
 hr {
 color: darkgray;
}

#navigation-container ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.menu-links{
  display: inline-block;
}

.languages{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Welcome </title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="text.css" type="text/css">
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 </head>
 <body>
   <div class="navigation-bar">


    <div id="navigation-container">

      <img src="Bildschirmfoto%202017-10-08%20um%2012.01.55.png">

      <ul>

        <div class="menu-links">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Who are we ?</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Newest</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">The Best</a></li>
        </div>

        <div class="languages">
          <li><a href="#">English</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Deutsch</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Français</a></li>
        </div>
     
      </ul>
        
    
        
     <hr >
    </div>
   </div>
  
 </body>
</html>
```